# Using rspec with Webrat instead of Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webrat, capybara

I have been using rspec with webrat and decided to add cucumber for high level tests.

After installing cucumber with capybara, for some reason rspec also switched to using it.

Is there a way to tell rspec to continue using webrat ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both webrat and capybara in your Gemfile, and add the following to your /spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
require "webrat"
Webrat.configure do |config|
    config.mode = :rails
end
```

I've just switched to capybara, but my view specs stopped working because capybara has no 'have_selector'. Guess you had a similar problem, well, now it's (hopefully) solved.